Using Vimscript, correct way get the current visual (or visual line or visual block) selection into a string
How do you shovel information from the current visual selection into a string?
I am trying to write a plugin for Vim 9.0ish for the ACL2 prover that shovels information into and (eventually out of) a :terminal. So far I don't have much, just some basic commands for starting a REPL session, loading files, loading visual selections, and trying to call certify. (It also currently requires stuff to be written in a very idiosyncratic style with a magic comment at the top. I am still learning how ACL2 does things.)
Also, neovim answers are fine. If neovim has a good API for doing this, I want to use it eventually.
One thing I need to do is take an active visual selection and put it into a string. So far I have been using this function (reproduced below) which works well for my purposes.
function! VisualSelection()
    if mode() ==# "v"
        let [line_start, column_start] = getpos("v")[1:2]
        let [line_end, column_end] = getpos(".")[1:2]
    else
        let [line_start, column_start] = getpos("'<")[1:2]
        let [line_end, column_end] = getpos("'>")[1:2]
    end
    if (line2byte(line_start)+column_start) > (line2byte(line_end)+column_end)
        let [line_start, column_start, line_end, column_end] =
        \   [line_end, column_end, line_start, column_start]
    end
    let lines = getline(line_start, line_end)
    if len(lines) ==# 0
            return ''
    endif
    let lines[-1] = lines[-1][: column_end - 1]
    let lines[0] = lines[0][column_start - 1:]
    return join(lines, "\n")
endfunction

This seems like the type of problem that should either have a dedicated API in Vim or a well-known plugin or a well-known incantation for solving, instead of several competing Stack Exchange answers that are over a decade old.
However, my attempts to find a better, more modern solution on this site have turned up nothing so far.

This question seems to be about setting the visual selections from vimscript
This question references this answer on Stack Overflow, which is another answer to the same question that I originally used for a VisualSelection function in the first place.
This question, which is about interacting with a different theorem prover, covers a different problem, selecting some kind of text object that's related to the prover's syntax.

So, with all that said, how do you shovel information from the current visual selection into a string?
Appendix A: Current draft of ACL2 plugin
Good for kicking the tires and hello world proofs but not much else. (For example, it's totally useless for hacking on the community books in https://github.com/acl2/acl2)
if exists("g:loaded_acl2")
    finish
endif
let g:loaded_acl2 = 1


" EnableHeader :: List -> List
function EnableHeader(lines)
  let g:enable_header_before = []
  let g:enable_header_header = []
  let g:enable_header_after = []
  let saw_begin_header = 0
  let saw_end_header = 0
  for line in a:lines
    if line ==# ";; BEGIN_HEADER"
      let saw_begin_header = 1
      continue
    endif
    if line ==# ";; END_HEADER"
      let saw_end_header = 1
      continue
    endif
    if saw_end_header
      call add(g:enable_header_after, line)
    else
      if saw_begin_header
        let new_line = substitute(line, ";; ", "", "")
        call add(g:enable_header_header, new_line)
      else
        call add(g:enable_header_before, line)
      endif
    endif
  endfor
  let combined = g:enable_header_before
  call extend(combined, g:enable_header_header)
  call extend(combined, g:enable_header_after)
  return combined
endfunction



" This is boilerplate for setting up a new book with a new package.
"
" Note that it is REDUNDANT.
"
" The community books style is to have something like add.acl2 beginning with
"
" ;; -*- mode: acl2; -*-
" (defpkg "ACL2-ADD"
"   (union-eq *common-lisp-symbols-from-main-lisp-package*
"             *acl2-exports*))
"
" (certify-book "add" 1 t)
"
" And then something like add.lisp which looks like:
"
" (in-package "ACL2-ADD")
"
" (defthm addition-is-associative
"  (= (+ x (+ y z)) (+ (+ x y) z)))
"
function! GetACL2Boilerplate()
  let name = expand("%:t:r")
  let name = toupper(name)
  let out = [
    \ ';; BEGIN_HEADER',
    \ ';; (defpkg "ACL2-%%%%"',
    \ ';;  (union-eq *common-lisp-symbols-from-main-lisp-package*',
    \ ';;   *acl2-exports*))',
    \ ';; END_HEADER',
    \ '',
    \ '(in-package "ACL2-%%%%")',
    \]
  let i = 0
  let max = len(out)
  while i <# max
    let out[i] = substitute(out[i], '%%%%', name, "g")
    let i = i + 1
  endwhile
  return out
endfunction


" From https://stackoverflow.com/a/47051271, Get the visual selection.
function! VisualSelection()
  if mode() ==# "v"
    let [line_start, column_start] = getpos("v")[1:2]
    let [line_end, column_end] = getpos(".")[1:2]
  else
    let [line_start, column_start] = getpos("'<")[1:2]
    let [line_end, column_end] = getpos("'>")[1:2]
  end
  if (line2byte(line_start)+column_start) > (line2byte(line_end)+column_end)
    let [line_start, column_start, line_end, column_end] = [line_end, column_end, line_start, column_start]
  end
  let lines = getline(line_start, line_end)
  if len(lines) == 0
    return ''
  endif
  let lines[-1] = lines[-1][: column_end - 1]
  let lines[0] = lines[0][column_start - 1:]
  return lines
endfunction


" send the visual selection to the first terminal, which is ACL2.
"
" suffix -- the suffix to add.
" fixup  -- whether to fix up the header
function! SendVisualSelectionToACL2(suffix)
  let terminal = term_list()[0]
  let visual_selection = VisualSelection()
  let visual_selection = join(visual_selection, "\n") . a:suffix
  call term_sendkeys(terminal, visual_selection)
endfunction


" send the entire buffer to the first terminal, which is ACL2.
function! SendBufferToACL2(suffix)
   let terminal = term_list()[0]
   " Use this incantation https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/313707
   let buffer_contents = getline(1, '$')
   let buffer_contents = EnableHeader(buffer_contents)
   let buffer_contents = join(buffer_contents, "\n") . a:suffix
   call term_sendkeys(terminal, buffer_contents)
endfunction


" quote a string in the lisp manner
function! LispQuote(string)
  return '"' . substitute(a:string, '"', '""', 'g') . '"'
endfunction


function! CheckCurrentFileWithACL2()
   let terminal = term_list()[0]
   " the book name is the file name without the extension
   let current_file = expand("%:t:r")
   " certify the current book and compile it.
   "
   " NOTE: do NOT pass the number of commands in the world to certify-book.
   " We don't want to say (certify-book "add" 0 t) for example.
   " That is because our REPL state is necessarily contaminated
   let certifier = printf("(certify-book %s |?| t)\n", LispQuote(current_file))
   call term_sendkeys(terminal, certifier)
endfunction


function! CertifyCurrentFileWithACL2()
   let terminal = term_list()[0]
   " the book name is the file name without the extension
   let current_file = expand("%:t:r")

   " get the current header.
   call EnableHeader(getline(1, '$'))

   let header = join(g:enable_header_header, "\n")

   " certify the current book and compile it.
   "
   " NOTE: do NOT pass the number of commands in the world to certify-book.
   " We don't want to say (certify-book "add" 0 t) for example.
   " That is because our REPL state is necessarily contaminated
   let certifier = printf("%s\n\n(certify-book %s 1 t)\n", header, LispQuote(current_file))
   let output = systemlist('acl2', certifier)
   echo join(output, "\n") . "\n"
endfunction


function! AddACL2Boilerplate()
  let buffer_contents = join(getline(1, '$'))
  call append(0, GetACL2Boilerplate())
endfunction


" I would really prefer this to be a function rather than a command.
"
" 1) move the directory to the directory of the current buffer. ACL2 likes to
"    drop files like *.port and *.cert in its current working directory.
" 2) Start the ACL2 terminal, split vertically
" 3) move focus back to original window.
"
command! StartACL2Term :cd %:p:h | :execute "vertical terminal acl2" | :execute "silent! normal! <c-w><c-w>"

" Send the visual selection over to the ACL2 buffer.
command! SendVisualSelectionToACL2 call SendVisualSelectionToACL2("\n")

" Send the whole buffer to ACL2
command! SendBufferToACL2 call SendBufferToACL2("\n")

" Add in some boilerplate.
command! AddACL2Boilerplate call AddACL2Boilerplate()

" Certify the current file
command! CheckCurrentFileWithACL2 call CheckCurrentFileWithACL2()
command! CertifyCurrentFileWithACL2 call CertifyCurrentFileWithACL2()

nnoremap \a :<c-u>StartACL2Term<cr>

vnoremap \s :<c-u>SendVisualSelectionToACL2<cr>
nnoremap \d :<c-u>SendBufferToACL2<cr>
nnoremap \c :<c-u>CertifyCurrentFileWithACL2<cr>
nnoremap \k :<c-u>CheckCurrentFileWithACL2<cr>
nnoremap \b :<c-u>AddACL2Boilerplate<cr>


Could you tell us how you would like to improve the solution you already have?

@VivianDeSmedt I'm after a standard way to do this, or confirmation that one does not exist either in Vim or Neovim.

Do you mean a dedicated API? I believe your script is still a very valid approach. There could be a slightly more compact way to do it in Lua. Are you interested by a Lua version? If so maybe could you be slightly more explicit about it in your formulation :-)

What's wrong with plain normal! "aygv ?

@Matt, assuming that that works if the visual region is currently active, nothing. (I don't know the details of gv, I've only used it a handful of times to get the previous visual selection) That's exactly the kind of thing I'm after, simple solutions to this problem that I just missed or don't know about.

If not in Visual yet then normal! gv"ay

The only practical way to "get the current visual selection into a string" is to yank it.
Usually, it is done like this:

Back-up target register.
Reselect text.
Yank selected text into target register.
Copy content of target register into variable.
Restore target register.
Return variable.

The backup-and-restore dance is not strictly necessary but we are yanking into an arbitrary register which might contain something important. Restoring the original content of the register before returning the yanked text is just more civilized and it removes the need to overthink the choice of register: just pick the first letter that comes to mind and off you go.
In practice:
function! GetVisuallySelectedText()
    " step #1
    let reg_a = getreg('a')

    " steps #2 and #3
    silent normal! gv"ay

    " step #4
    let visually_selected_text = getreg('a')

    " step #5
    call setreg('a', reg_a)

    " step #6
    return visually_selected_text
endfunction

See :help getreg(), :help setreg(), :help :normal, :help gv.
